# Read files in the order of the timestamp from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to read files from a folder that is present on the Azure VM in the same order in which they are created and load the data to Azure SQL DB.

Using Logic Apps/ADF, whenever there are 1000 files loaded at once, it picks up randomly from them, but how to read them sequentially, in the order of the timestamp and process them?

Note: Everyfile will have a time stamp in its name(Filename_Timestamp.xml)

Comment: Consider making your process resilient to the files not being loaded in order.

Comment: Did you using the foreach active?

Comment: I have an idea that you could using Get Metadata active to get all the filename list, then add a copy activc in foreach active to loop copy the file.